# Creating / wrapping DocumentFragment in MooTools JavaScript library

Tags: dom, mootools, documentfragment

How to do equivalent of the following pure JavaScript fragment with [MooTools](http://mootools.net/)

```
x = document.createDocumentFragment();
x.[fill with nodes];
document.[somewhere].appendChild(x);
```

In particular as described in [DOM 2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) after attaching fragment to DOM the original variable `x` becomes **empty** [DocumentFragment](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-B63ED1A3):

> If it *[the node to add]* is a DocumentFragment object, the entire contents of the document fragment are moved into the child list of this node

---

**Edit** *(2011-04-13 06:30 UTC)*:

What I'd like to get is something that behaves both as ***DocumentFragment*** from DOM 2 Core, but has all nice methods of ***Elements*** from MooTools Core.

Comment: What about this plugin? http://mootools.net/forge/p/element_fragment